# Execute code only after a Javascript forEach/map

Tags: javascript, foreach, async-await

I have a `forEach` function that loops through an array of files, uploads the file to Firebase Storage and then after the upload, it stores the image reference link into a array defined before.

Process of each iteration:

- Take file object and convert to Blob
- Upload Blob onto Firebase
- After Blob uploads, receive a callback which has the image reference of the upload
- Store the image reference in a list

After the `forEach`, I use the list of image references for further processing. **However, when I try and reference the list, it is usually empty because this code executes before any images upload (and references are not recieved). How can I use async/await with a Javascript forEach function where I can invoke my code to wait where it should expect a populated image reference list**. I've already tried to find a solution on stackoverflow but hasn't helped toward my solution.

```
submitPost = async event => {

event.preventDefault();
const img_names = [];

this.state.files.forEach((ref_, index) => {
  ref_.current.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(blob => {

    var uploadTask = this.storageRef
      .child("images/" + String(index))
      .put(blob);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      snapshot => {
        var progress =
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        img_names.push(uploadTask.snapshot.ref.toString());
      }
    );
  });
console.log(img_names) // empty here
});
```

Comment: It is easier to help if you add some code to what you have already tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that functionality by using `map` instead of `forEach`. Convert your array into an Array of Promises. Then use that array inside a `Promise.all()` and await it.

```
const promisifyUpload = (storageRef, ref_, index) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ref_.current.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(blob => {

      var uploadTask = storageRef
        .child("images/" + String(index))
        .put(blob);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        snapshot => {
          var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
        },
        error => console.log(error),
        () => resolve(uploadTask.snapshot.ref.toString())
      );

    });
  });

};

const submitPost = async event => {

  event.preventDefault();

  const img_names = await Promise.all(
    this.state.files.map((ref_, index) => promisifyUpload(this.storageRef, ref_, index))
  ));

  console.log(image_names); // Should now be filled
});
```

**Edit**: I split it up into 2 functions to show isolate the "promisify" logic

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Working on the using the above concept on my code. someUploadFunction takes `resolve` as an argument and returns the  result?

Comment: I updated my example to show how to apply that to your code :)

Comment: This is really sick, I think this is almost working. When i log it onto the console, it shows as an array of Promises that are pending. I am also using this in a React component btw.

Comment: Glad this is of help! If the log shows the pending promises, I think you might have forgotten the `await` keyword?